# PHP query won't work from HTML href link

Tags: php, html, sql

Am creating a webpage which allows me to search for locations by county. I am trying to create an href link on my basic homepage which will call to a Php function and then display results from my Sql database.
Not sure why but when I click on the href link the homepage just goes blank, no values returned. Have been over code and database, have shown to a few friends and can't figure out what's wrong. Any help appreciated!

This is my index.php main homepage code (with href about halfway down)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<?php
include("includes/db.php");
include("getAntrim.php");
include("functions/functions.php");
?>


<html>

<head>

<link rel = "stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" media = "all"/>

<title>Location Scout</title>

</head>

<body>

<!-- Main container starts -->

<div class ="main_wrapper">

<div id="form">
<form method="get" action="results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" name="user_query" placeholder="Search for location"?>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search"/>

</form>
</div>

<div class ="content_wrapper">
<div id ="left_sidebar">
<div id="sidebar_title">Search by County</div>

<a href="getAntrim.php">Antrim</a><br></br>


<div id ="content_area">
<div id ="products_box">

<!-- THIS IS WHERE FETCHED DATABASE INFO WILL GO -->


<?php
getAntrim();

?>


</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Main container ENDS -->

</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is my getAntrim.php function, which should sort through sql database and then return stated values.

```
<?php

    include ("includes/db.php");

    if (isset ($_GET['getAntrim'])) {

        $get_loc_co = "select * from locations where county='Antrim'";
        $run_loc_co = mysqli_query($db, $get_loc_co); //Gets data from db and presents on main  page

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($run_loc_co);

        if ($count==0) {

            echo "<h2>No locations found in this category.";

        }//if

        while ($row_loc_co=mysqli_fetch_array($run_loc_co)) {

                //variable to store values
                $loc_id = $row_locations['loc_id'];
                $loc_name = $row_locations['loc_name'];
                $town = $row_locations['town'];
                $county = $row_locations['county'];
                $productions = $row_locations['productions'];
                $disabled = $row_locations['dis_access'];
                $parking = $row_locations['parking'];
                $visitor = $row_locations['vis_facs'];
                $transport = $row_locations['public_trans'];
                $cost = $row_locations['cost'];
                $accom = $row_locations['accom'];
                $latitude = $row_locations['latitude'];
                $longitude = $row_locations['longitude'];
                $description = $row_locations['loc_desc'];
                $keyword = $row_locations['loc_keyword'];
                $loc_image = $row_locations['loc_img'];


                echo "
                <div id= 'single_location'>
                <h3>$loc_name</h3>
                <img src = 'Admin_area/location_images/$loc_image' width='180' height = '180'/><br>
                <p><b>Productions: $productions </b></p>
                <p><b>Description: $description </b></p>

                </div>
                ";

        }//while
    }//if


?>
```

Am first time poster, so hopefully have posted this ok! Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Your code doesn't work and the error is likely found in an error log somewhere (depending on the web server).

Comment: Your overwriting your `$run_loc_co` variable here `while ($row_loc_co=mysqli_fetch_array($run_loc_co)) {` change it to `while ($row_locations=mysqli_fetch_array($run_loc_co)) {`

Comment: Thanks cmorrissey. have tried that and the other suggestion below and now coming up with other error messages. Have pasted screenshots in a new answer below.

Answer (score 1):

you're checking for a query parameter, which you're NOT passing in:

```
<a href="getAntrim.php">Antrim</a><br></br>

    if (isset ($_GET['getAntrim'])) {
                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

`$_GET` contains url query parameters, e.g. `example.com?foo=bar` (the foo=bar portion). Since you have NO query parameters in your `href`, the `isset()` properly returns false, and your entire db code section is simply ignored.

You probably want

```
<a href="getAntrim.php?getAntrim">Antrim</a><br></br>
                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

to make this work as-is.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Have tried that and getting some error messages now. Have pasted in screenshots if you are able to look.

Comment: your queries failed, you hav e no error handling, and used the boolean falses the query call returned as if it was a result set, causing further errors.

Comment: Ok, am not sure what you mean but will take another look over. thanks again.

Comment: `null give`: you didn't connect to the DB properly, or `$db` is not your database connection handle. that means your query() fails, and returns a failure statement. since that's not a result., num_rows fails as well.

Comment: basically: you write code as if nothing could EVER go wrong, which is exactly the WRONG attitude. never EVER assume success when dealing with external resources (especially databases). even if the SQL syntax you wrote is 100% perfectly valid, there's a near infinite number of other ways for it to fail (e.g. bad foreign key, database crashed, network dead, blah blah blah). Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Ah ok so it's a connection issue then. I'll take good look and figure it out.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, it was a connection issue which I have now fixed. Got the results returning ok. I'm a newbie to all this Php/Sql stuff, so appreicate your help with this greatly! Thanks.